# What does "Did the very weak " mean?

Tags: idioms-in-context

[image: You tuve comment]

Hi there!Could somebody please tell me what is the meaning of this expression?
You'll find it in the John Monroe first comment, almost at the bottom.

Comment: Probably not in order to point out that 'John Monroe' sounds kind of, well, _stupid_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think *weak* is a typo and it was intended to say *the very week*. As in:

> since JFK did [bring attention to the deep state "shadow government"]
> the very week he was assassinated

Meaning that JFK did that on the week he was assassinated.

Comment: Thank you very much!